# Using RestTemplate GET request throws 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate, spring-webclient

I am getting 400 Bad Request when I send a GET request to Rest Service from JUnit Test case. My request body should be `text/plain` (`Content-Type: text/plain`) and the response should be a `ResponseEntity` of type `Employee`.
I am not getting any error when I call request using Postman, but how I'm not able to make it pass using Spring Web Client methods.

I have an example for a POST REQUEST where almost similar test implementation passes, the difference is that in the request body I pass an entire object of `Employee` and in the test which fails is a `text/plain`. ( Last added)

I tried to understand why it doesn't work, but I couldn't figure out.
I also tried to change exchange Method with `getForObject`, `getForEntity` but it didn't work.

Full URL : http://localhost:8080/employee/find/lastName/

L.E.: IntelliJ hellps me by highlighting .exchange method and tells me that that method will respond with 400.

#### Controller

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/find/lastName", headers="Content-Type=text/plain", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> findEmployeeByLastName(@RequestBody String lastName) {
        return EmployeeService.getEmployeeByLastName(lastName);
    }
```

#### Service

```
public static ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployeeByLastName(String lastName) {
    return employees
            .stream()
            .filter(employee -> employee.getLastName().equals(lastName))
            .findFirst()
            .map(employee -> new ResponseEntity<>(employee, HttpStatus.OK))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ExmployeeResourceException("Not Found"));
}
```

#### JUnit Test

```
@Test
public void ShouldReturnEmployeeByUsingLastName() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    String employeeLastName = "Doe";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(employeeLastName, headers);
    ResponseEntity<Employee> responseEntity =
            restTemplate.exchange(
                    HOSTNAME + ENDPOINT + "find/lastName/",
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    request,
                    Employee.class
            );
}
```

#### Error log

```
22:12:28.619 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [Doe] as "text/plain" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@48075da3]
22:12:28.764 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - GET request for "http://localhost:8080/employee/find/lastName/" resulted in 400 (null); invoking error handler
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
    at com.endava.rest.EmployeeTests.ShouldReturnEmployeeByUsingLastName(EmployeeTests.java:90)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

#### Example of test which passes

```
    @Test
    public void ShouldBeAbleToCreateAnEmployee() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        Integer id = 3;
        String firstName = "Ionut";
        String lastName = "Popescu";

        Employee newEmployee = new Employee(id, firstName, lastName);
        HttpEntity<Employee> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(newEmployee);
        ResponseEntity<Employee> responseEntity =
                restTemplate.exchange(
                        HOSTNAME + ENDPOINT,
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        httpEntity,
                        Employee.class
                );
}
```

Comment: What does the log contain on the server side?  What is the actual value of `HOSTNAME + ENDPOINT + "find/lastName/"`?  There's a lot of necessary information missing.  Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: The value is: http://localhost:8080/employee/find/lastName/, it can be seen in "Error". Thank you for advices :)

Comment: Since your `GET` has no body, the `Content-Type` header doesn't make much sense. Try setting the `Accept` header instead (in the test). Does it work?

Comment: @acdcjunior My request have a body which is a text (string) that's why I added the Content-Type header. I've tried your solution, but the only change is that the response code changed from 400 to 406.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was on mobile and didn't notice that. I posted an answer now. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My request have a body which is a text (string) that's why I added the Content-Type header.

The `RestTemplate` client doesn't support entities in `GET` requests. This is lack of support for body in `GET`s pretty common in clients, given those kinds of APIs are rare.

[More info on `RestTemplate` specifically](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20978#issuecomment-453466705):

> I assume you are using a `RestTemplate` with a default `ClientHttpRequestFactory`. In this case, JDK's `HttpURLConnection` is the underlying HTTP client. `HttpURLConnection` does not send a request body for GET requests; I've verified that using Wireshark.

If you really are stuck with `RestTemplate`, your alternative is to use a different `ClientHttpRequestFactory`. For instance:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import java.net.URI;

class HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryForGetWithBody extends HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory {
    private static final class HttpGetRequestWithBody extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {
        public HttpGetRequestWithBody(URI uri) { super.setURI(uri); }
        @Override public String getMethod() { return HttpMethod.GET.name(); }
    }
    @Override
    protected HttpUriRequest createHttpUriRequest(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri) {
        if (HttpMethod.GET.equals(httpMethod)) {
            return new HttpGetRequestWithBody(uri);
        }
        return super.createHttpUriRequest(httpMethod, uri);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryForGetWithBody());
```

Comment: Thank you for this, thix partially fixed my problem. This it's working only if Request responses with Success, if the status code responses with 404 it doesn't work ( I want to test a 404 scenario ).

Comment: I found the problem, I had to implement an ErrorHandle for response. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling

Comment: Alright, cool. Glad you got to figure it out. That makes sense, because using a custom request factory does require you to fill some additional holes. Cheers!

Comment: We concider this as a dirty work-around, however very useful temporary solution until they fix the API. So thank you a lot for this priceless hint!